# STM32 development board design

Tags: stm32, low-power, battery-operated, swd, development-tools

I am making a board to learn STM32 with a future Li-Po battery powered project in mind. The aim of the project is to have a device that wakes up a couple of times a day on its own and can also be woken up manually, hence battery life and longevity are important. And this is what I came up with: [image: miniature_dev_board_circuit]

Naturally I have accumulated a couple of questions. Here they are in the order of relevance :

1. Is linear voltage regulator a bad solution for a low power device? I plan on supplying peak 40 mA with a couple of pins for a couple of seconds several times a day. And to improve Li-Po longevity I want to cut off battery at 3 Volts.
2. It it *that* bad sinking more than 15 mA with a non-FT-f pin? Let's say 20 mA top for a couple of seconds?
3. Is Q1 battery voltage monitor a good design? Since Vbat can't be supplied with higher than 3.6 Volts. My reasoning is that voltage divider will be draining current constantly and Q1 might be a reasonable solution for prolonging battery life. Plus gate charge is low enough(<7nC) not to require a resistor(?).
4. Can I substitute an ST-Link with an FTDI232 board I have lying around to flash the chip? Because I am so cheap.
5. A question out of curiosity. Is C8(Vref+ bypass) redundant? I have designed it with reference to the datasheet and some application notes, but on this IC Vref+ and Vdd pins are so close I thought it might be useless.

I have been always interested in electronics, but have almost no formal education in EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe. The regulator will consume power to work itself, and it will need to dissipate power based on MCU consumption. If MCU idles most of the day, then efficiency could be enough. You do the math and decide.
2. Yes. Any design relying on built-in protection features is a bad design. Check if it exceeds nominal or absolute maximum ratings. Exceeding nominal ratings means the MCU does not damage but it does not have to work in out-of-spec conditions. Exceeding absolute maximum ratings mean damage.
3. No that is a bad design. When Q1 is is of, battery current will flow into MCU via protection diodes. It may bring MCU VDD higher than 2.5V out from regulator.
4. Yes if your MCU factory bootloader supports UART and you make circuitry to enable the MCU to go into factory bootloader.
5. It depends what the MCU requires. Two 100nF in parallel is better than one. It might or might not work, but it might depends what the MCU does. Best to go with manufacturer suggestions.

Comment: Thanks,
3. Yes, definitely a blunder on my part, there was an npn, I switched it out for a fet. Didn't even consider higher voltage anyway. Will a high-side pnp work?

4. Doesn't this option with USART include debugging? Can't wrap my head around "circuitry to enable the MCU" part. Is it bootloader activation pattern? The documentation says "yes", there is a bootloader, but "boot pin is shared with a standard GPIO and can be enabled through the boot selector option bit". So I need SWD to flip this bit and then flash it with USART? :D

Comment: 3) no because you can't turn off a high side pnp referenced to Vbatt 4) no of course it won't allow debugging as it's an UART not a SWD adapter. I don't know the defaults for that chip.